# Missing Gem Dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, kramdown

I am experiencing a problem with my build and missing a gem. However, I've installed the gem multiple times to no avail. I'm using NPM to manage packages as well. Since Jekyll is looking for kramdown, a gem, how can I let my build know it's installed locally?

Apologies on the weird question. I'm new to gems and stuff.

My error:

```
    Warning: Command failed: You are missing a library required for Markdown. Please run:
  $ [sudo] gem install kramdown
  Conversion error: There was an error converting 'project/adrian-college.md'.
             ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                    ------------------------------------
                    Missing dependency: kramdown
 Use --force to continue.
```

**SOLUTION**

'gem install kramdown' installed the gem locally but wasn't included as a dependency for the project. I had to simply edit the Gemfile manually and add: `gem 'kramdown'` then run `bundle install`.

Comment: I should note, the default MD library, redcarpet works just fine. I'm trying to use a different MD library.

Comment: Explanation of why this was down voted would be helpful in crafted better questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your question, you should just have to type :

```
gem install markdown
```

that will auto-install the dependencies.
It worked fine for me.

Comment: It didn't work because it didn't add it to my gemfile. I had to manually add the gem kramdown entry to my gemfile and run 'bundle install again'

Comment: what is your error message when you type : gem install markdown ? 
alternatively, you can manually install the dependencies.
https://rubygems.org/gems/markdown

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this?